# $k$ valued points of projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I‘m pretty sure that I saw an answer on this site sometime ago that might help me now. However, I couldn’t find it anymore, so eventually I gave up and asked for myself:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. I want to see that the closed points in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ can be identified with the set of homogenous coordinates $x=(x_0:\ldots:x_n)$, where I map such a latter one with $x_i\neq0$ to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}^{i}$ generated by $$\left(\frac{X_0}{X_i}
-\frac{x_0}{x_i},\ldots,\widehat{\frac{X_i}{X_i}-\frac{x_i}{x_i}},\ldots,\frac{X_n}{X_i}-\frac{x_n}{x_i}\right)$$ inside the coordinate ring of the i-th standard affine open $$D_+(X_i)=\operatorname{Spec}k\left[\frac{X_0}{X_i},\ldots,\widehat{\frac{X_i}{X_i}},\ldots,\frac{X_n}{X_i}\right].$$ Then I need to see that this is well-defined, that is, if also $x_j\neq0$, then $\mathfrak{p}^{i}$ and $\mathfrak{p}^{j}$ glue to the same point in $\mathbb{P}_k^m$. This means that $\mathfrak{p}^{i}$ and $\mathfrak{p}^{j}$ coincide as ideals in $$k\left[\frac{X_0}{X_i},\ldots,\widehat{\frac{X_i}{X_i}},\ldots,\frac{X_n}{X_i},\frac{X_i}{X_j}\right].$$ For this, I need to see that for $k\neq i,j$, we have that $$\frac{X_k}{X_i}
-\frac{x_k}{x_i}$$ and $$\frac{X_k}{X_j}-\frac{x_k}{x_j}$$ differ by a unit.

However, this I don‘t see. Just a small hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your last two math expressions are identical.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you, I fixed it now.